# Available Memory for a process

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the available memory in a process to ensure I do not get an OutOfMemoryException.  I have searched the internet and found several examples of how to get memory *used* but not *available*.

Let me provide the use case...

I have a process that is doing a Bulk Insert (using SqlBulkCopy).  I am passing a `DataTable` into the `WriteToServer` method.  I cannot use a `DataReader` because I have to be able to retry the process upon failure.  My first thought was to pick an arbitrary number of rows to insert at a time, say 50,000.  But this is a generic process that does not know the data; it does not know the number of columns nor the amount of data in each row.  So I was thinking I could monitor the memory as I am adding rows to the `DataTable` and then post it to the `SqlBulkCopy` when it got close to running out of memory.

Is this a valid approach or is there a better way?
If this is a valid approach, what function would I use to determine the amount of available memory?

Here is my code so far...  The `AvailableMemoryIsLow` is what I cannot figure out how to determine.

```
// m_buffer is a read-once cache (implements IDataReader) that pulls 
// data from an external source as needed so it uses very little memory.
// My original implementation just used m_buffer as the parameter of 
// WriteToServer but now I have to add retry logic into the process.

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(m_tableName);
foreach (DataField d in m_buffer.GetColumns())
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(d.FieldName, d.FieldType));

while (m_buffer.Read())
{
    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_buffer.FieldCount; i++)
        row[i] = m_buffer.GetValue(i);

    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

    // How do I determine AvailableMemoryIsLow
    if (rowCount++ >= 50000 || AvailableMemoryIsLow)
    {
        PutDataIntoDatabase(dataTable);
        dataTable.Clear();
        rowCount = 0;
    }
}

if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    PutDataIntoDatabase(dataTable);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you are running this code on a 32-bit machine or you wouldn't have this problem.  In general, pushing a program to consume nearly all of the available virtual memory space (2 gigabytes) is not a reasonable thing to do.  Short from the ever-present danger of OOM, the kind of data your are handling is "live data", it is highly likely to be mapped to RAM.  A program that demands nearly all available RAM is pretty detrimental to operation of that program, the operating system and other processes that run on that machine.

You force the operating system to start choosing how to allocate RAM between what the processes need as well as what it reserves for the file system cache.  That kind of choice always ends up forcing data from RAM into the paging file.  That can slow down operation a great deal, both when it is written and again when a process needs it back in RAM.  An operating system perf problem called "thrashing".

Just don't do this, dunking so much data in RAM just doesn't make your program any faster.  It makes it *slower*.  A reasonable upper limit on the amount of RAM you consume on a 32-bit operating system hovers somewhere near 500 megabytes.  There isn't any need to hit *exactly* that limit, counting rows is quite good enough.

Comment: The challenge I have is that I do not know the data.  Each row could potentially take megabytes of memory, so picking the correct number of rows is the challenge for me.  I am just guessing that any number I pick we will have a client that ends up exceeding this.

Comment: I'm not buying yet, a single row consuming megabytes of data is a rather gross dbase design problem.  Ultimately there's code that fills in the columns of a row, surely you can add counting to that as well.

Comment: After much deliberation, taking all this input into account, and discussing with my co-workers, it was decided I was indeed over-analyzing the problem and making it too complicated.  I ended up counting rows with a max row count stored in the .config file with a default of 50,000.  Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you found methods that tell you how much memory is allocated

```
    GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
```

is one such method (which I presume you have already found).

One thing that I would like to point out from the MSDN documentation.

> Retrieves the number of bytes currently thought to be allocated

This is at the very top of the GC.GetTotalMemory method documentation.  I would like to point out the word **thought** in the above phrase.  Now I know you know how to find the allocated amount as it is mentioned in your question, however I bring this up to illustrate that C# is a managed language.  Memory usage and consumption is abstracted away from you and even the GC methods are merely there to give you a vague idea of what is going on in your process.  Working with memory levels manually sounds risky and unreliable to me.

I would recommend going with your original approach but pulling the batch size way back to a level such that it is highly unlikely that you get an out of memory exception no matter how many columns you are working with.  Think hundreds, perhaps a few thousand, rather than tens of thousands.  Any performance gains you get by larger batches are likely to be outweighed by the risk of memory problems at these levels even if you try to detect that.  The performance tools mentioned in another answer would be a great way to determine what the batch size should be and if it is even a problem.

Comment: This is a very good point.  There are corner cases where one row may contain a huge amount of content so that even setting it to 1000 rows at a time would cause an OutOfMemoryException, but let me give this some thought.  Maybe the extreme corner cases should just be ignored.  It would sure be nice if .Net provided some way to "warn" you before memory ran out...but I do understand why that don't / can't.

Comment: @GeneS: After considering the answer by Hans, I think it would be best to roll the batch size back to such a level that all reasonable cases don't even approach memory consumption levels that might issue OOM exceptions.  Bulk insert may not be worth it if you are having huge amounts of memory consumption let alone OOM exceptions.  At the very least the batches may need to be limited significantly more than previously thought.  Again, a good use of the profiling tools mentioned by paulsm4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are lots of different kinds of "resources"; any one of which can manifest themselves with an "OutOfMemoryException".

Probably your best bet, however is `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)`.

And even better approach would be to get a tool like JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), or RedGate [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler).

IMHO ...

PS:

If you're doing SQL Bulk Copy, be sure to set EnableStreaming:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.enablestreaming.aspx

Comment: What could dotTrace or RedGate do?  This code needs to run in production.  Also, GC.GetTotalMemory does not tell me the amount of `available` memory.

Comment: My point is there's no single "magic number" that's going to help you - things are more complicated than that.  The best you're going to do (for a .Net program) is probably "GC.GetTotalMemory(false)".  Along with `Process.WorkingSet64, Process.VirtualMemory64` (sorry I didn't mention that).  Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021714/memory-usage-of-strings-or-any-other-objects-in-net

Comment: If memory is a concern, I honestly think your best bet is to familiarize yourself with a good tool (like ANTS and/or dotTrace; like Rational Purify in earlier days) and stress test your program in-house to identify any potential leaks, bottlenecks or hot spots.  IMHO...